# $xx$ application in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm just getting started with lambda calculus and I see that the fixed-point $Y$ combinator is defined as:

$Y = \lambda f . (\lambda x . f(x x))(\lambda x . f(x x))$ (*)

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#anApplic) that something like $t s$ (where $t, s$ are both terms) represents an application of a function $t$ to the input $s$, so in (*) I suppose that $x x$ represents the application of $x$ to the input $x$.

The problem I have with that interpretation is that it supposes that $x$ is itself a function (or an *abstraction*, as defined in the article).

However, in general $x$ seems to just denote a *variable* so how should I understand $x x$?

Answer (score 2):

You're right: $xx$ is the application of $x$ to $x$. But this is not a problem as long as you remember that you're only dealing with *syntax* here: $x$ is a term, $x$ is another term, so $xx$ is a term.
In particular, to form an application term $MN$, you do *not* suppose that $M$ is an abstraction.

Another way to put this is that in λ-calculus, *everything is a function*, not only the abstractions. $x$, in particular, is a function that you can apply to any argument.

Of course, in a typed setting terms like $Y$ raise typing issues. But you're doing untyped λ-calculus here, so you don't need to find a well-formed type for $x$.

By the way, having this kind of weird (at first sight...) behaviour is precisely what makes λ-calculus interesting as a computation model.

Answer (score 1):

in $\lambda x . f(xx)$, you are correct to say that $x$ is the variable of a lambda abstraction. However, a variable is simply a placeholder for the substitution that happens when the lambda abstraction is applied to some argument. Consider the following application:
$$ (\lambda x . f(x\,x))\,y \;\to_\beta\; f(y\, y)  $$
The way you evaluate any application $(\lambda x.t)s$ is by substituting every instance of $x$ in $t$ with $s$.

In the example above $t$ is $f(x\,x)$, and $s$ is $y$, therefore you substitute all the $x$'s in $f(x\,x)$ with $y$'s, obtaining $f(y\,y)$. In this case $y$ is a free variable, but in the case of he $Y$ combinator it's bounded, therefore $y$ could be substituted with any possible $\lambda$-term.

Now that the semantics is clearer, you may ask what would it mean to "feed a function to itself" as its own input. Consider the following combinator (*combinator* is just a name for a $\lambda$-term with no free variables):
$$ \Omega = \lambda x. x x $$
What would it mean to apply this term to itself?
$$ \begin{aligned} \Omega\,\Omega &= (\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x)\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda x. x x)(\lambda x. x x) \\ &\to_\beta \;... \end{aligned} $$
Since every time we substitute the two $x$'s in the expression $x\,x$ with the term $(\lambda x . xx)$ we obtain a new term: $(\lambda x . xx)(\lambda x . xx)$. This happens to be precisely what we started with, and therefore if we keep applying the beta-reduction rule we will always end up where we started; the evaluation never terminates.

If we now come to the $Y$ combinator, we can show that it has a similar property. Notice what happens when we apply $Y$ to a lambda-term $F$.

$$ \begin{aligned} Y F &= (\lambda f . (\lambda x . f(x x)) (\lambda x . f(x x)))F \\ &\to_\beta (\lambda x . F (x x))  (\lambda x . F (x x)) & (1) \\ &\to_\beta F (\lambda x . F (x x)) (\lambda x . F (x x)) & (2) \\ &= F(YF) & (3)
 \end{aligned} $$
In (1) we simply substitute the $f$ variable for the term $F$. In (2) we substitute the $x$'s in $F(x x)$ with $(\lambda x . F (x x))$, and (3) follows from the fact that we are obtaining line (1) with an $F$ applied to it.

The fact that $YF = F(YF)$ (i.e. $YF$ is a *fixed point* of $F$) implies that: $$YF = F(YF) = F(F(YF)) = F(F(...F(YF)))$$
And therefore applying the $Y$ combinator to any term $F$ basically applies the term to itself forever. This can be used to write "recursive functions" in the lambda calculus.

Sorry if that was a bit long, I just thought that taking it step by step would help you better understand what is meant by $x\,x$.